# How to clear added elements in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a Select field, which inserts an component into the parent element depending on the value.
Code example:

```
@ViewChild('parentStuff', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

constructor(
    private _cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver
) {}

onChange(event): void {
    // how to clear here the other components?
    let comp = this._cfr.resolveComponentFactory(SubRule);
    this.container.createComponent(comp);
}
```

If the user changes the selection box frequently, the item is hung underneath.

How can I remove the items that were previously added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `ViewContainerRef` to hold the injected component ,you can use the `clear()` method to clear added component from view. Please note that `clear()` will remove all the elements added to the container.

```
this.container.clear();
```

If you just want to remove a **specific component**, you can use it's index to find and remove it from view:

```
  let componentRef: ComponentRef<MyComponent> = 
       this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
  const containerIndex: number = this.container.indexOf(componentRef)

    // removing component from container
    this.container.remove(containerIndex);
```

Comment: Glad, it helped!